# Script doesn't work in crontab but works in the terminal

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, centos

I'm attempting to run a bash script in crontab on Centos 5.5 but i don't see it running as a pid (pid -e). The script itself uses an awk command to monitor a running log for a keyword then sends an email, then once the server is back online it sends a confirmation email:

```
tail -fn0 user | awk '
    !server_down && /disconnect_tcp_conn/ { 
        system("mail -s \"server down\" mail@gmail.com </dev/null") 
        print "server down"
        server_down = 1 }
    server_down && /daemon apps started/ {
        system("mail -s \"server's back!\" mail@gmail.com </dev/null") 
        print "Server's back!"
        server_down = 0 }'
```

Originally, I had trouble with running the script while the terminal was closed. Someone suggested using setsid in the following way:

```
setsid server_mon.sh >/dev/null 2>&1 < /dev/null &
```

And this works great.. until it doesn't. For some reason, after some time like a day or so, the script no longer sends notifications. So, I thought to create a cronjob for the script.

Not being familiar with bash shell and not much of a programmer i tested the script in cron every minute to see if i was using it right:

```
* * * * *  /var/log/server_mon.sh
```

Didn't work. It would only say:

```
"/tmp/crontab.XXXXmu99ii" 19L, 760C written
crontab: installing new crontab
```

Tried to use rc.local.. can't. I think the centos version is too old (5.5), plus, the crontab might be the way to go because i might want to find out at what point the notifications seems to stop working and set up a cron job accordingly.. at least until i have time to fix it.

tried adding the path to the awk command in the script: /usr/bin/awk
Still no pid.

tried adding the following changes from what i found on the web:

```
setsid bash -lic 'cd /var/log && exec SLR_reaper.sh -start' </dev/null &>/dev/null &
```

didn't work, and not sure if it's right.

my expected result is to get this:

```
setsid server_mon.sh >/dev/null 2>&1 < /dev/null &
```

somehow to be triggered by crontab:

```
@reboot /var/log/server_mon.sh

       *or*

* * * * * /var/log/server_mon.sh
```

Just to see it work.

Any direction or help would be great. If you need more info please let me know also. Thanks!

A screen shot of the log sent to mail:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhSzT.jpg)

Comment: Try doing `* * * * * /bin/sh ./var/log/server_mon.sh`

Comment: Just tried it. Still no pid

Comment: If you weren't redirecting stderr to /dev/null then you probably wouldn't be saying `For some reason` wrt why `setsid server_mon.sh >/dev/null 2>&1 < /dev/null &` fails as it's probably printing the reason why it fails to stderr.

Comment: Are you suggesting I remove /Dev/null then? Should I try that?

Comment: Shellcheck produces [5 findings](https://pastebin.com/PfUYPRgb) for your code. You should fix them before continuing.

Comment: I'm suggesting that when any command is failing you should be trying to see any error messages it's producing. So yes, get rid of the `>/dev/null 2>&1` and any other redirections to `/dev/null`.

Comment: @Ed Morton good suggestion. I need to see what’s going on exactly

Comment: @jww nice. never knew about shellcheck. I will try to use it and see if it works for me.

Comment: You seem to have a problem with crontab. Crontab works in a limited environment, so PATH will not contain all paths which you normally have in a default shell. Have a look at [My crontab is not working and how can I troubleshoot it](https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/) for how to troubleshoot a crontab.

Comment: I believe crontab is working because i just tested it by adding the following in crontab: * * * * * /bin/date >> /tmp/cron_output                                                                                                        The output:                                                                                                               Tue May 14 09:51:01 PDT 2019
Tue May 14 09:52:01 PDT 2019

Comment: @Ed Morton. Sorry, today had no time. Found something useful though. The Crontab logs are being sent to a mail folder. I can send more details in the form of screen shots tomorrow but for now I can say there’s an error pertaining to “user” file not being located. Possibly a path issue? User is the name of the log file the script searches for keywords in. Again, the script finds the file no problem when launched from the prompt but not called from Crontab.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like you need to provide the full path to `user` in the script. I can't imagine how it worked for a while from cron and then stopped given that unless there was a file named `user` in the directory it runs in that got removed while it was running.

Comment: @EdMorton yup! hit the nail on the head my friend.

Answer (score 1):

So the solution was pretty simple. I just had to provide the path to the file the script was monitoring, in the script itself:

```
tail -fn0 /var/log/user | /usr/bin/awk '
    !server_down && /disconnect_tcp_conn/ {
        system("mail -s \"server is down XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX\" mail@gmail.com </dev/null")
        print "server is Down XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"
        server_down = 1 }
    server_down && /daemon apps started/ {
        system("mail -s \"Server is up XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX\" mail@gmail.com </dev/null")
        print "Server is Up XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"
        server_down = 0 }'
```

The log file reported that it couldn't find the file which clued me to it being a path related issue.

Previously the script read:

```
tail -fn0 user | /usr/bin/awk '
```

Now I added the full path:

```
tail -fn0 /var/log/user | /usr/bin/awk '
```

Kudos to @EdMorton for telling me to track the log and then provide the full path in the script. I didn't realize this was necessary because the script was in the same directory as "user".